# Failed to link whem trying to flash code to esp32 with tinygo

Tags: go, esp32, tinygo

I'm trying to make a simple Hello World with tinygo and esp32, but I get an error when I upload it.
In that context, a hello world would be a led blink.

`

```
package main

import (
    "machine"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    println("START")

    var pin machine.Pin = 2
    pin.Configure(machine.PinConfig{Mode: machine.PinOutput})

    for {
        pin.Low()
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)

        pin.High()
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
    }
}
```

`

to upload it to the esp32, I'm using:

`tinygo flash -target=esp32-coreboard-v2 -port=/dev/ttyUSB0 test1.go`

(test1 is the name of the file).
Then the following error occurs:

`error: failed to link /tmp/tinygo456060352/main: exec: "xtensa-esp32-elf-ld": executable file not found in $PATH

How can I fix it ?`

I tried exposing the global path and changing the usb port of the esp32.
I was expecting that the code would be uploaded.

Comment: Did you read the instructions for setting up TinyGo for the ESP32 and install ESP-IDF?

Comment: Just did it, but still get the same error